# Define CustomMetadata Type with API

Tags: custom-metadata

I am trying to define a CustomMetadata type via an API. Any (Apex, REST etc) API is ok.

So far I have only been able to create new instances of the type but I have not been able to define the type itself via an API.

**Is there a way to define a CustomMetadata type through an API?** ie can I use an API to achieve the same as [described here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_ui_create.htm)

Comment: I have used Apex to create MetadataAPI. If you need, i can share that.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below solution for creating Custom Metadata Type using apex class

https://www.sfdcpanther.com/create-update-custom-metadata-using-apex/

Comment: That solution creates a custom metadata *record* in Apex, of a type that was created using the Setup UI. The Metadata namespace in apex supports upsert of custom metadata records, but not the types themselves (although the full MD API does support the types, as specialized CustomObjects).

Answer (score 0):

From a Metadata API perspective, a custom metadata type is just a CustomObject with "__mdt" instead of "__c" at the end of its API name. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadatatypes.htm for a full description of special properties of/restrictions on such files.